# IE11 error when running webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am working on a VueJS application and its not working out in IE11. I get blank pages and an error that states "Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference" on this line:

`// Return the exports of the module
return module.exports;`

My webpack.base.config.js file:

````
```module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js'],
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
    : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...(config.dev.useEslint ? [createLintingRule()] : []),
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },```
````

My package.json (shortened for brevity)

````
```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "basscss": "^8.0.2",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.11.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0"
}```
````

Can anyone help? Been trying to solve this for a couple of days now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldnt solve it so I set up my project from scratch and got it working in IE except for some scrolling functionality. Posting this because it may help out someone else.

Set up a new project using vue-cli (works in IE)
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Then copied main.js from original project imports one by one to the new main.js file. Installed dependencies as needed.

I got an error at this point, saying:

```
You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available.
Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
```

Read some docs and then in main.js file, I replaced

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  i18n,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

with

```
new Vue({
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Then the Sass files did not work: needed to install sass-loader

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev
```

Now my SCSS files were compiling.

IE broke when importing https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scrollto (for the scrolling functionality) in main.js. Left this out of my app for now but the app is now working in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that was solved by installing polyfill 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill

```
npm install promise-polyfill --save-exact
```

Hopefully that helps, IE is always a pain

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and rebuilt but no change. Do I have to import anything to the main.js file? Or just install?

Comment: Ah sorry, i gave the wrong polyfill, ill put another answer

Answer (score 0):

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill.html

try installing this one instead and following the steps that explains where to call polyfill in webpack and main.js

```
npm install --save @babel/polyfill
```

Comment: Yes, it does with no console errors. I added my package.json (above). Maybe this would give a clue?

Comment: It will be an issue to do with polyfill

Comment: Ok :) I will keep at it and post the solution once i find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try adding import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill'; to main.js file